# Sudo validates command line arguments via regular expression incorrectly

Tags: configuration, sudo, regex, regular-expressions

Let's say we have two users: alex and alexa. We want to allow alex to execute `htop` as root in order to see disk usage stats, but we do not want them to see other users' processes which root can do. Then it is needed to allow them executing `htop` with the `-u` flag being their own username ***(important note: as @HBruijn mentioned, specifying the user flag in `htop` does not prevent executor from changing user filter by U key; let’s pretend the flag does limit the executor to illustrate the issue)***. But we also need to check that the last specified `-u` argument is `alex`, plus we do not want to force it being the last specified argument. The regexp comes as follows:

```
^.*(--user=alex|-u alex)\b((?!-u).)*$
```

- `^` indicates the string start
- `(--user=alex|-u alex)` - the capturing group for the `-u` parameter
- `\b` - word boundary (so alex could not specify `-u alexa`)
- `((?!-u).)*` - negative lookahead that denies any `-u` passes after the valid one (`-u alex`) has been passed

And we write it to the `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
echo "alex ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/htop ^.*(--user=alex|-u alex)\b((?!-u).)*$" >> /etc/sudoers
```

However, when alex tries to execute a normal command, sudo denies them:

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/htop -u alex 
[sudo] password for alex: 
Sorry, user alex is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/htop -u alex' as root on machine.
```

When checking regexp through `egrep` (sudo documentation states that it is similar to how it validates strings through regexp) it works as expected:

```
$ echo '-u alex' | egrep '^.*(--user=alex|-u alex)\b((?!-u).)*$'
-u alex
```

What causes this behavior of sudo ignoring that match? Using Ubuntu 22.04, Sudo 1.9.14p3.

Comment: Currently on mobile so I can’t check , but once `htop` is launched with `-u Alex` can’t alex use the `u` keybinding in htop to change the user filter and see (and manage) other users processes anyway ?

Comment: And does sudo even do full regular expression matching ? When I read https://www.sudo.ws/docs/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man/#Wildcards I see a warning *”Note that these are not regular expressions.”*

Comment: @HBruijn about htop - you indeed can change user filter according to the manpage. But at least we can specify readonly flag, haven’t seen a way to cancel that from the htop itself. If we want to do that, we still have the same regex issue.

Comment: @HBruijn about regex support by sudo - you can use them since 1.9.10 (https://www.sudo.ws/posts/2022/03/sudo-1.9.10-using-regular-expressions-in-the-sudoers-file/). As I have mentioned in the end of my post, I am using sudo 1.9.14p3. I only updated the main sudo binary though but I doubt that’s the problem.